# Login to multiple accounts using the same loop statement

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

All I need is a more reliable and stable way of logging into multiple account (not all at once) using a loop that's all. I have already an example code that works but isn't all that stable.

```
string email_1 = "email_1";
string password_1 = "password_1";
string email_2 = "email_2";
string password_2 = "password_2";

int k = 1;
do
{
            string e = null;
            string p = null;
            if (k == 1)
            {
                e = email_2;
                p = password_2;
            }
            if (k == 2)
            {
                e = email_1;
                p = password_1;
            }
        _driver.FindElement.(id("submit_email")).sendkeys(e);
        IWebElement s = _driver.FindElement.(id("submit_password"));
        s.Sendkeys(p);
        s.Submit();

        //do stuff

        _driver.FindElement(id("logout")).Click();
            k++;
} while (k <= 2);
```

Any ideas on how to make it more stable and reliable, or maybe a better approach to it?

Comment: What do you mean by "stable"?

Comment: a code that logs in each time I want it to, while this code fails sometimes.

Comment: well where does it fail. I think mostly will fail in the //do stuff region .. And also its not clear how you got the driver and came to the login page.. Try to put all your code and what all "unstable" things that you are seeing in the post. because we cant test your code (what you have provided) to find out where it fails("unstable")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're gonna need to completely refactor this code. Have you ever practiced object oriented design?

Create this class:

```
public class Account    // Stores the email and password of each account
{
    public string Email;
    public string Password;

    public Account(string email, string password)    // Constructor
    {
        Email = email;
        Password = password;
    }
}
```

Then use this class like so:

```
// Keep all the accounts in one place
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>()
{
    new Account("email_1", "password_1"),    // Create a new account
    new Account("email_2", "password_2")    // Create another account
};

foreach(Account account in accounts)
{
    _driver.FindElement.(id("submit_email)).sendkeys(account.Email);
    IWebElement s = _driver.FindElement.(id("submit_password"));
    s.Sendkeys(account.Password);
    s.Submit();

    // do stuff
    _driver.FindElement(id("logout")).Click();
}
```

This code is highly expandable and reusable. If you want to add another account, you use the `new Account(string, string),` statement in the `List` and that's the only change that needs to be made.

Comment: for some reason you approach is much smoother and faster than the one I wrote, it works for me way better than my code. so thanks a lot austin.